# Application Initialization in Azure Function Project in VS2017 15.3.4?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

In Visual Studio 2017 with the latest update, for azure functions template, I want something where I can initialize like program.cs in webjobs template.

I am trying to create a new subscription with new namespace Manager when application initializes so that I can listen to one service bus topic.

Is there a way to do that? If yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to create a subscription that this Function will be triggered on, there is no need to do that manually. Function App will create the subscription based on your binding at deployment time.

For other scenarios (e.g. timer-triggered function), you can do the initialization in a static constructor:

```cs
public static class MyFunction1
{
    static MyFunction1()
    {
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);
        if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists("topic1", "subscription1"))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateSubscription("topic1", "subscription1");
        }
    }

    [FunctionName("MyFunction1")]
    public static void Run(
    // ...
}
```

Static constructor will run at the time of the first function call.

Comment: Thanks! But, the above function will not be triggered unless there is a message on the queue and then the constructor will be called. In the above case, we are gonna create the queue in static constructor. Thus, the above will not work since we want to create the queue before the function gets triggered.

Comment: @Vicky Ah, are you trying to create a subscription which function listens to? Function App will create it for you, once you deploy the Function.

Comment: Yes. So, does it create a queue/subscription when the function app deploys. Following code is what I am talking about before listening to message to service bus.                                                                                                     
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists("queue"))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue("new QueueDescription("queue"));
        }

Comment: @Vicky Yes. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for asking follow up questions. We are bit naive on azure functions stuff. How about publishing message back to queue from the function and what if the queue does not exists while publishing. Also a different question, is there a way to create a filter while creating subscription as you said while deployment?

Comment: is there a way to create a filter on the subscription based on the brokered message property so that we receive only those messages that matches with the filter. This needs to happen before function gets invoked by first message in topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> for azure functions template, I want something where I can initialize like program.cs in webjobs template.

As far as I know, Azure functions do not have good support for this right now. You can find [a similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/433c82fe-4aa7-4dc7-9cd0-8b899d52738c/function-initialization?forum=AzureFunctions):

> **Question:**
>
> *I have a C# function and want to know if there is any Initialization point. I have dependency injection containers that need initialization
>   and want to know where to do that.*
>
> **Mathew's reply**
>
> *We don't have a good story for this right now. Please see open issue
>   [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/586) in our repo where this is discussed.*